# Button click event inside clickable ion-card executes parent event too

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, dom-events, stoppropagation, event-propagation

I am creating an ionic app that fires a modal when I click on a card, the problem I'm facing is that when I click a button on the card, the modal opens as well, how do I stop this from happening. I am open to any workarounds as I have been stuck on this for awhile. Below is some useful code and pictures:

```
//html
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col size="6" *ngFor="let item of exercises">
        <ion-card class="exercise-card" (click)="openModal(item.id)">
          <img [src]=item.image class="image-card">
          <h3 style="font-weight: bold;">{{item.name}}</h3>
          <h5>{{item.sets}} sets of {{item.reps}} reps and {{item.remarks}}</h5>
          <h6>{{item.date | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}} ({{item.time}})</h6>
          <br>
          <div style="text-align: center;">
            <ion-button size="medium" style="width: 30%;" color="success" (click)="complete(item)">
              <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="checkmark-outline"></ion-icon>
            </ion-button>
            <ion-button size="medium" type="submit" style="width: 30%;" [routerLink]="['/edit-exercise', item.id]">
              <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="create-outline"></ion-icon>
            </ion-button>
            <ion-button size="medium" style="width: 30%;" color="danger" (click)="delete(item)">
              <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="trash-bin"></ion-icon>
            </ion-button>
          </div>
        </ion-card>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
```

The modal should only fire when : click the cards on this page:

[image].

But instead it fires when I click the blue edit button as well:

[image: here].

Comment: did my answer work?

Comment: @MahdiZarei didn't test it, already fixed it with my own answer

Comment: I think you have to learn a way that can be used in any situation. not a made-up one. try my way if you want to learn something useful for good.

Comment: @MahdiZarei, tried ur solution, didn't work with my example, plus i submitted this assignment 2 weeks ago

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it called event propagation. it means that when you trigger an event all same events of parents will be executed. to prevent that, you can do something like this for example:

in this tag, when you execute `complete()` function, pass the $event too:

```
<ion-button size="medium" style="width: 30%;" color="success" (click)="complete($event, item)">
```

in complete() function add this line:

```
function complete(event, item) {

  //your code

  event.stopPropagation();
}
```

**stopPropagation()** prevents the parent click event to be executed.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve it by wrapping the image and the headers in a `div` and adding the `click` event to the `div`.

```
//html
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col size="6" *ngFor="let item of exercises">
        <ion-card class="exercise-card">
          <div (click)="openModal(item.id)">
            <img [src]=item.image class="image-card">
            <h3 style="font-weight: bold;">{{item.name}}</h3>
            <h5>{{item.sets}} sets of {{item.reps}} reps and {{item.remarks}}</h5>
            <h6>{{item.date | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}} ({{item.time}})</h6>
            <br>
          </div>
          <div style="text-align: center;">
            <ion-button size="medium" style="width: 30%;" color="success" (click)="complete(item)">
              <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="checkmark-outline"></ion-icon>
            </ion-button>
            <ion-button size="medium" type="submit" style="width: 30%;" [routerLink]="['/edit-exercise', item.id]">
              <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="create-outline"></ion-icon>
            </ion-button>
            <ion-button size="medium" style="width: 30%;" color="danger" (click)="delete(item)">
              <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="trash-bin"></ion-icon>
            </ion-button>
          </div>
        </ion-card>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

In case more events need to be triggered (reload/update), wrapping different sections in the div tags will be effective.
I faced the same issue and this worked for me, however - event.stopPropogation didn't.